# How to get wordpress main query posts as an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the main query posts as an array. Example, in common tag page(tag.php), I need to get all the posts as an array ( like get_posts() do) and display it using some multiple loops instead of using default wordpress loop as shown under

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$posts` is the variable you're looking for it. It is the equivalent of `get_posts` results for the main query. It's in the global namespace, so in order to access it somewhere else you'll need to use the keyword `global`.

```
global $posts;
foreach( $posts as $a_post ) {
    echo $a_post->post_title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I edit some of those arguments like orderby, etc to get the correct posts that i am looking for

Comment: $posts is the result of the main query. In order to modify this query, use query_posts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts